# Why do some white blood cells have lobed nuclei?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology

Several types of white blood cells (eg Neutrophils) have lobed nuclei.  Is this for a functional reason?  I have seen people refer to structural differences in the lobes as indicative of problems, but I have not been able to find why the nuclei form into lobes in the first place.  Is this known?

Comment: [The Neutrophil Nucleus and Its Role in Neutrophilic Function](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25727365) is the most recent review article I could find, but you'll need institutional access. Basically there's still not a lot of consensus and this is an active field of research. A big reason that stands out is the need to migrate through tissues, and  the lobular nucleus may assist there.

Comment: Thanks!  I do have an academic affiliation, so I will check out the article.  Thanks for tracking it down!

Comment: @Kendall for those without access to the review, could you summarize it as an answer?

Comment: I am not sure if this is why their nuclei are the way they are, but this may be one of the coolest functions of the immune cells. [Extracellular traps are associated with human and mouse neutrophil and macrophage mediated killing of larval Strongyloides stercoralis](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1286457914000306) Bonne-Année et. al. Basically Neutrophils are capable of using their chromatin to set extracellular traps for large pathogens such as nematodes that are too big to phagocytose. They die as a result , but the are able to "chuck out" their DNA at the worm.